# Best practices for isolating malware/honeypot samples

Tags: security, virtual-machines, malware

I am pursuing malware research and am wondering what are the best practices for building safe VM's to contain the code while disassembling it.  So far:

1. Each instance for examining the code is housed in a seperate VM with host-only network support to prevent hostile code from escaping the VM.
2. Each VM is fully patched and has a minimal attack surface by excluding all unnecessary software/services.

What other steps should I take to isolate the VM's or harden the VM's ?  The VM's are Win XP and Win Vista.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a malware sandbox, not a honeypot.

I would recommend having the host machine be a different OS than the sandbox. For example, run Linux on your VM, then run the malware in a Windows installation inside the linux VM. It would be shocking if the Windows malware infected the Linux box.

There is actually an open source system called [Zero Wine](http://zerowine.sourceforge.net/) you could take a look at.

Its sole purpose is to help people analyze malware in a contained environment.

There are some commercial products such as [Norman Sandbox Analyzer](http://www.norman.com/enterprise/all_products/malware_analyzer/norman_sandbox_analyzer/en-us) that might be viable as well, depending on your budget.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't sound exactly like you're working with a honey pot, but rather a test system in which to examine malware.

Be aware that it's possible for malware to get outside the VM, and even replace the VM's hipervisor with a malicious one.  You'll need to make sure the system on which the VMs are running is incapable of causing you harm - for example, an air gap between it and your network.  You'll also want backups of the system in a clean state, prior to any viruses, and probably bootable write-once media from whcih to restore.

Comment: Currently, there is no known malware that can "escape" a vm/replace the hypervisor. Blue Pill http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Pill_(malware) is poc, and has not been seen in malware in the wild. For future reference, please post references for such claims

Comment: @Josh Brower:  You may well be correct in that there is no malware currently getting outside the hypervisor.  There is, however, a difference between, "malware can" and "malware does".  I'll try and call out such syntactic details when I write future comments.

Comment: @ atk: Was not trying to be offensive. Just trying to be accurate.

Comment: @Josh Brower: I apologize for the tone of my response.  You are correct in that my original comment implies more than I meant.